# File_get_contents только отдельный элемент

Tags: php

Я гружу страницу со стороннего ресурса с помощью file_get_contents('url') и с помощью echo вывожу всю страницу на свою. Можно ли как-нибудь вывести не всю страницу, а только отдельный фрагмент/элемент?

Comment: Можно.

1. Загружаете страницу.
2. Находите фрагмент/элемент.
3. Выводите его.
4. Profit!

Comment: А второй пункт поподробнее можно?

Answer (score 1):

Регулярные выражения, preg_replace, подробнее можно посмотреть тут: [ТУТ](http://php-include.ru/stati/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-php)

Что касается парсинга HTML нашёл для себя несколько наработок, выложу тут может Вам или кому ещё пригодятся:

```
Картинки .GIF                       /<img[^>]+?gif.*?>/si
Аттрибут background                 /\s+background=[^\s>]*/si
Аттрибуты элементов HTML            /\s+ATTRIBUTE=[^\s>]*/si
Комментарии HTML                    /<!— .*?—>/si
Дублирующиеся возвраты каретки      /([\r\n])[\s]+/si
Неразрывные пространства            /&(nbsp);/si

Двухдескрипторный тэг HTML, без содержимого
/<TAGNAME.*?>(.*?)<\/TAGNAME.*?>/si

Двухдескрипторный тэг HTML вместе с содержимым      
/<TAGNAME.*?>.*?<\/TAGNAME.*?>/si

Двухдескрипторный тэг HTML с определенным аттрибутом,без содержимого
/<TAGNAME.*?ATTRIBUTE=["']*VALUE["']*.*?>(.*?)<\/TAGNAME.*?>/si

Двухдескрипторный тэг HTML с определенным аттрибутом вместе с содержимым
/<TAGNAME.*?ATTRIBUTE=["']*VALUE["']*.*?>.*?<\/TAGNAME.*?>/si

Закрывающийся тэг HTML
/<\/TAGNAME.*?>/si

Однодескрипторный или открывающий двухдескрипторный тэг HTML
/<TAGNAME.*?>/si

Однодескрипторный или открывающий двухдескрипторный тэг HTML с определенным аттрибутом
/<TAGNAME.*?ATTRIBUTE=["']*VALUE["']*.*?>/si

Ссылки на почтовые адреса без якоря
/<a.*?href=["']*mailto.*?>(.*?)<\/a.*?>/si

Ссылки на почтовые адреса с якорем
/<a.*?href=["']*mailto.*?>.*?<\/a.*?>/si
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть много способов: preg_replace, SimpleXML, simple_html_dom. Выбирай любой.
Страницу тебе стягивать по любому нужно, потом парсить с помощью каких то инструментов (3 я уже перечислил, их больше и зависят от того, что тебе нужно распарсить), а потом уже выводить тот кусок, который нужен.

Comment: К этому можно добавить [Класс DOMDocument][1]. Людям, знакомым с JS, разобраться элементарно, да и вообще ничего сложного. @scarian, вот вам [инфа для раздумий][2].

   [1]:http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php
   [2]:http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Answer (score 0):

не забываем, что HTML может быть невалидным (да, и такое бывает представьте) и большинство парсеров запнутся/пропустят кусок в случае незакрытого тега или там, допустим ковычек нет, поэтому желательно конечно полученный текст приводить к валидному виду. Если вам повезло и на серваке установлено расширение PHP - php_tidy, то это просто замечательно - читаем 
[недлинную документацию к нему](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/tidy.html.php)

в другом случае пользуемся отдной из возможных 
[альтернатив](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-tidy.html)